# How to authorise action in a controller using CanCan ability?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorization, cancan

I'm using `CanCan` gem for authorisation in my Rails project.

The `ability.rb` file look something like:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    @user = user || User.new
    send @user.role.name.underscore unless @user.role.nil?
  end

  private

  def partneradmin
    can :manage,  :all
    cannot :access, User, role_id: @user.role.id
    cannot :manage, Watchlist
    can :manage, Attachment
  end

end
```

I have another controller `controllers/admin/users_controller.rb` which looks like:

```
class Admin::UsersController < AdminController

  load_and_authorize_resource

  respond_to :html, :json

  def index
  end

  def new
  end
end
```

Now I want to restrict access to `Admin::UsersController#index` action so `partneradmin` user can't access the action. I tried to add `cannot :access, Admin::UsersController` but with no luck as I can still access `Admin::UsersController#index` page.

Please note that I don't want to restrict access for all Users resources. As for example I have `PartnerAdmin::UsersController#index` and I don't want to restrict it but only for `Admin::UsersController#index` (based on the controller and not model).

Comment: What is rails version? `rails -v`

Comment: How can you whether the user is `partneradmin` when you have the `user` object? I there a `user.is_partneradmin?` methods? Is it a boolean field in the DB?

Comment: @MattGibson yes I have `is_partner_admin?` method to check.

Comment: Cancan gem is for rails 3 from what I remember. You should be using [Cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) its really easy to use and its better then Cancan.

Comment: @Fresz I'm already using  'cancancan', '~> 1.8.4'

Comment: Cancan and Cancancan are two different things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to add `cannot :index, AdminController` so `ability.rb` would look:

```
  def partneradmin
     can :manage,  :all
     cannot :access, User, role_id: @user.role.id
     cannot :manage, Watchlist
     can :manage, Attachment 
     cannot :index, AdminController
   end
```

Then to add `authorize_resource :class => AdminController` in the controller.